# Process finishes with exit code 0

Tags: pycharm

I have the code, it works but it does not produce the graph it is supposed to. I have matplotlib installed.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def weight_reduction():
    current_weight = float(input("Enter your current weight (in pounds): "))
    desired_weight = float(input("Enter your desired weight (in pounds): "))
    weight_loss = current_weight - desired_weight
    dietary_habits = float(input("Enter your current caloric intake (in calories): "))
    exercise = float(input("Enter your current exercise level (1-5): "))
    daily_deficit = dietary_habits - exercise
    try:
        days = int(input("Enter the number of days you would like to track your weight loss: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a valid number of days.")
        days = int(input("Enter the number of days you would like to track your weight loss: "))
    weight_loss_per_day = weight_loss / days
    daily_caloric_intake = dietary_habits - weight_loss_per_day * 3500 / 7
    x = [i for i in range(days)]
    y = [current_weight - i * weight_loss_per_day for i in range(days)]
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.xlabel("Days")
    plt.ylabel("Weight (in pounds)")
    plt.title("Weight Reduction Progress")
    plt.show()
```

I tried the code and expected a graph.

Comment: Exit code 0 indicates the process finished without any error. Have you checked the tab "Plots" in "SciView"? [Scientific mode](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/matplotlib-support.html#sm)

Comment: it is in pycharm

Comment: not sur e how to do that

Comment: Have you just defined the function, or have you called it as well?